# TableViewCell scroll selects wrong cells when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My tableview highlights the wrong cells when I scroll up and down. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I'm trying to add the `.Checkmark` accessory view as well as change the font of `cell.textLabel?.text`. Upon scrolling, random rows are selected and the ones I manually select sometimes deselect.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.array[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

        if cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark {

            cell.accessoryType = .None

            cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16)
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None {

            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

            cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)
        }

            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Please share you complete code regarding your `UITableView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare array which will keep track of which rows are selected:

```
var selectedRows:[Bool] = []
```

You need to make sure that it is populated with the same number of items as your data array.

Then modify your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.array[indexPath.row]
        if selectedRows[indexPath.row] {
            // row selected
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
        else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }

    return cell

}
```

And in your `didSelectRow` function add line:

```
selectedRows[indexPath.row] = !selectedRows[indexPath.row]
```

When you modify your cell from `didSelectRow` the next time cell is dequeued it will have the accessory type which you set. The reason why it happens after scroll is because when you scroll the cells which become visible get dequeued. So, you need to manually set correct accessory type for them

Comment: Afraid I'm having the exact same problem, except this time there are no checkmarks after selecting a row

Comment: @dperk have you checked the last version? I had a mistake in the initial code.

Comment: I'm getting a nil value/crash at ` if selectedRows[indexPath.row] {`. Wondering why...

Comment: @dperk did you make sure that it has the same number of items as your data array?